# Insert my own QML Button into a GridLayout

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout

I´m new to Qt and want to have some Buttons (made in a seperate .qml file with Rectangle...) in a GridLayout. Unfortunately it seems like it doesn´t positions the Buttons to different cells. Everything is in the first row/column. Is there a variable for the ID necessary, like an array? Or QML dynamic objects?
Here the Button:

```
Item {
property string textOnButton: "Test"
property int w: 130
property int h: 100

Rectangle{
    id: emptyRectangle
    width: parent.w
    height: parent.h
    Text {
        text: parent.parent.textOnButton + parent.index
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.parent.horizontalCenter
        topPadding: 6
        font.pixelSize: 30
    }
 }
```

}

And here the GridLayout where the Item should be placed in a few times:

```
GridLayout{
    id:grid1
    rows: 3
    Layout.margins: 20
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    columnSpacing: 10
    rowSpacing: 10
    EmptyButton{
        id: eins
        textOnButton: "HELP"
    }
    EmptyButton{
        id: zwei
        textOnButton: "HELP"
    }

}
```

Later I want to use different colors/text on the button and switching different lights for instance.
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: what do you want to do? what is the right behavior in your opinion? what size do you expect the button will be? the Item has no size in your code. what a sense to wrap the Rectangle with Item? did you try to put your item in all the cells?

Comment: @folibis The size isn´t important, like some other informations in my code. I just want to place some rectangles as buttons (made in EmptyButton.qml) in a gridlayout with a different ID for triggering later different actions. But I don´t have a clue how to get different ID´s and at the same time that is obviously the problem that the gridlayout doesn´t put my EmptyButton´s into different cells. In the code there is now only one, but if I use a repeater for example. 
Sorry, my question was not precisely formulated

Comment: Apparently if I don´t use the Item and just the Rectangle, it puts them into the grid

Comment: I have written a qml tutorial which might be usefull for you. See https://github.com/xxxcucus/planes/releases The file is called TheGameOfPlanes.0.2.3.pdf See the chapter PlanesQml. You have there examples of GridLayout, GridView, GridView. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width and height of the GridLayout and all of the other items

```
GridLayout{
    width: 500
    height: 500
    id:grid1
    rows: 3
    Layout.margins: 20
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    columnSpacing: 10
    rowSpacing: 10
    EmptyButton{
        id: eins
        textOnButton: "HELP"
    }
    EmptyButton{
        id: zwei
        textOnButton: "HELP"
    }

}
```